# IE9 Document standards and Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, internet-explorer-9

I have a weird problem that I am hoping someone can help me with.

I have a web app running jquery and I am trying to run it in IE9. When I try to load the first page, it appears broken and I know that document.ready() and window.load() are not firing. When I use the developer tools in IE9 and change the document standards to IE8 or IE7 it all works just fine, just not with the document standards set to IE9.

My question is what has changed here that is killing my app? Has anyone had experience with this that might be able to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps some sample code would be really helpful. :) And it's not really `document.ready()` --- it's `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Does IE9 in Standards mode throw an error?

Comment: No, there is no error at all, that is what I find so weird. I have used the developer plugin but there are no errors or anything. I do know that I wrote the syntax incorrectly for the ready event, but I have it right in the app. thanx ;). In IE9, when I toggle to IE8 standards there is no problem with IE9 standards the ready event doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using latest jquery (1.5.1 at the time of writing). There were compatibility issues with older versions and IE9.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think this problem might be related to something other than JQuery. I've had exactly the same problem with IE9 and Firefox on Mac (works fine with dev tools, not otherwise). If it's the same problem, it relates to use of console.log(). A suggested fix is to replace:

console.log(message)

with

if (typeof console != "undefined")
   console.log(message)

Comment: The console object doesn't exist any version of IE or in older versions (possibly all) of FF (but Firebug adds it).  Attempting to reference it will cause an error about undefined variables, which is not happening, so it's definitely not related to the problem.

Comment: The solution provided by doclm actually solved the issue for us. It might not be what caused the issue for the OP but it definitely is a valid suggestion.
@El Yobo: In IE 9 calling `console.log()` does output to the console in the developer tools. So the console object does exist in IE 9, at least when the developer tools are opened.

Comment: It wasn't what caused the problem for the OP, because they reported getting no errors.  As mentioned, this will cause an undefined variable error if no console object is available, which makes it pretty clear what the problem is.  I downvoted in this case because it was clearly unrelated to the OP problem.